# Symfony 4: entity relation cascade "remove" Doctrine doesn't detect change

Tags: symfony, doctrine, relation

I have an entity which had this relation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Contract", inversedBy="childContract", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $parentContract;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Contract", mappedBy="parentContract", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $childContract;
```

My schema was generated and I was working with this until now, that I decided to take out the `"remove"` part:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Contract", inversedBy="childContract", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $parentContract;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Contract", mappedBy="parentContract", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $childContract;
```

But if I execute command:

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql
```

I get output:

> [OK] Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

The fact is, when I try to delete a contract, Doctrine tries to delete child contracts, and I get this exception (this is, it's trying to delete child contract):

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM contract WHERE id = ?' with params [2098]:
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`prestazoom`.`contract`, CONSTRAINT `FK_E98F28594E5AF28D` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_contract_id`) REFERENCES `contract` (`id`))

If I check contraints over this table, with this SQL command:

```
SELECT 
  r.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
  r.DELETE_RULE, 
  r.TABLE_NAME,
  GROUP_CONCAT(k.COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR ', ') AS `constraint columns`,
  r.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS r
  JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k
  USING (CONSTRAINT_CATALOG, CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA, CONSTRAINT_NAME)
-- using MySQL's GROUP BY clause. In other DB's more columns would need to be
-- specified!
WHERE r.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'prestazoom' and r.TABLE_NAME = 'contract'
GROUP BY r.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG,
     r.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
     r.CONSTRAINT_NAME;
```

I get this output:

`| FK_E98F28594E5AF28D | RESTRICT    | contract   | parent_contract_id | contract |`

Which is not cascade delete? I don't really know, and I don't know why it's trying to delete child contract.

Hasn't it detected I removed "cascade" restriction? Is it another problem?

Comment: Doctrine doesn't create CASCADE DELETE on your SQL schema when you specify cascade delete on your relation. It handles it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the behavior at the relation level when deleting the object/entry. Here you want the `parentContract` to be null on child deletion.

In Doctrine, you can achieve this with `onDelete` attribute.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Contract", inversedBy="childContract", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_contract", referencedColumnName="child_contract", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $parentContract;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Contract", mappedBy="parentContract", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $childContract;
```

Comment: Sorry, couldn't try till now. This throws an error: 
> The annotation @ORM\OneToOne declared on property App\Entity\Contract::$parentContract does not have a property named "onDelete".

It's symfony 4, maybe OnDelete doesn't work here.

Comment: Yes, edit in this way, onDelete has to be on JoinColumn